# how to clear js timer from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

i need help here i just want to stop the timer started by the setInterval() in js
but in another i have to stop this timer 
please tell me if is this possible to kill all timer in the page using jquery or js

This is the function where i started the timer : -

```
function get_question(cat_id){
    //count = parseInt(count) + 1;

    $('#action-options').show();
    var user_id = '<?php echo $user->ID; ?>';
    if(cat_id=='')
    {
        var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();;
    }
    var roomid = $('#roomid').val();
    /*var round = $('.round').find(h4).html();
    console.log('round : ',round);*/
    var current_round = counter;
    //console.log(current_round);
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php"); ?>',
        type : 'post',
        data : { action : 'get_question', cat_id : cat_id, roomid : roomid,current_round : current_round , user_id : user_id},
        success : function(res){
        //  console.log('current question :',res);
            $('.round').html("<h4>Round "+counter+"</h4>"); 
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            $('.questions').html('');
        //  console.log('length',res.length);
            for(x=0;x<res.length;x++)  
            {
            //  console.log(res[x]);
                //var parsedjson = JSON.parse(res[x]);
                var parsedjson = res[x];
            //  console.log('data :',parsedjson);
                if(parsedjson['options'])
                { 
                var arr = parsedjson.options.split(","); 

                $('.questions').append('<div class="question_text'+x+'" data-id="'+parsedjson.id+'"><h3>'+parsedjson.questions+'</h3></div><div class="options'+x+'" id="pik"><input type="radio" name="options'+x+'" value="'+arr[0]+'"><label>'+arr[0]+'</label><input type="radio" name="options'+x+'" value="'+arr[1]+'"><label>'+arr[1]+'</label><input type="radio" name="options'+x+'" value="'+arr[2]+'"><label>'+arr[2]+'</label><input type="radio" name="options'+x+'" value="'+arr[3]+'"><label>'+arr[3]+'</label> </div> ');
                }
                else{
                    $('.questions').append('<div class="question_text'+x+'" data-id="'+parsedjson.id+'"><h3>'+parsedjson.questions+'</h3></div><div class="options'+x+'" id="kip"><input type="text" name="answer'+x+'" > </div> ');
                }
            }
            var time_limit =0;
            //var   counter = 1;
                $.ajax({
                url : '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php");?>',
                type : 'post',
                data : {action : 'get_round_time',counter : counter, cat_id : cat_id},
                success : function(response){
                //  console.log('response',response);
                var round_no = counter;
                    time_limit= response;
                //  console.log(time_limit);
                         start_timer = window.setInterval(function(){
                        var timer = time_limit-1; 
                            time_limit=timer;
                            //limit = timer;
                            if(timer==0)
                            { 
                                $('#action-options').css('pointer-events','');
                                $('#action-options').css('cursor','');
                                $('.questions').html('');
                                $('.round').html('<h4>Round '+counter+'</h4>');
                                check_current_round_answers(round_no);
                                if(counter==3)
                                {

                                    if(timer==0) 
                                    {

                                            $('.timer').html('Please wait for your results !'); 
                                            $('.questions').html(''); 
                                            clearInterval(start_timer);
                                            get_final_results();
                                            return false;
                                    }

                                }
                                //console.log('current_round : ',current_round);
                                counter = counter+1;
                                $('.timer').html('');
                                clearInterval(start_timer);
                                get_question(cat_id);

                            }
                          $('.timer').html('<h4>'+timer+'</h4>');

                        }, 1000);
                }

            });






        }
    });
}
```

and here is my second function in which i want to stop the timer

```
function check_current_round_answers(round){
    console.log('current round : ',round);
    var roomid = $('#roomid').val();
    var user_id = '<?php echo $user->ID; ?>';
    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type : 'post',
        data : { action: 'get_round_result',round:round, roomid:roomid, user_id : user_id},
        success : function(val){
            console.log(val);
            if(val.indexOf('turn skipped')!=-1)
            {
                console.log('start_timer ',start_timer);
                clearInterval(start_timer);
                var name = '<?php echo $user->display_name; ?>';
                get_final_results();
                var d = new Date();
                var params = {
                    'message': name+' has skipped',
                    'action': 'message',
                    'timestamp': d.getTime()/1000
                };
                conn.send(JSON.stringify(params)); 
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are using `start_timer` in both the functions. According to the code i don't see it is declared anywhere.

Use a global variable and declare it outside the both functions.

`var set_timer;`

Or you can also use window object in the case of global usage (not recommended .. but in case you use this make sure you don't overwrite the existing window properties)

Replace `start_timer` with `window.start_timer`.

**If you have more than one `setInterval`** then create a global array variable and store each setInterval into it. Simply loop this array and clear intervals.

Answer (score 0):

I took 10 seconds to look at your code (there's too much of it), but all the code you need is this:

```
var intervalID;

function ticker(){
    console.log("tick");
}

function startTicking(){
    intervalID = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
}

function stopTicking(){
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}
```

That's one method `startTicking` starting an interval and another method `stopTicking` stopping (clearing) the interval. `intervalID` is a declared variable accessible by both functions.

From the code you posted, `start_timer` hasn't been declared so would become a global variable: `window.start_timer`

On the other hand, if you have incorrectly declared `start_timer`, it may not be accessible where you are trying to use it. For example this **doesn't work** (ticks forever):

```
function ticker(){
    console.log("tick");
}

function initTicker() {
    var intervalID;

    function startTicking(){
        intervalID = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
    }

    startTicking();
}

function stopTicking(){
    clearInterval(intervalID); // Uncaught ReferenceError: intervalID is not defined
}
```